# Parsing arguments in Linux. Full stop becomes zero

Tags: shell, parsing, unix, command-line

I am having a shell script which accepts 2 arguments.
I run it as follows

```
myscript.sh 2015.0J.Oct 8.0.3
```

Inside the script I have lot of complicated stuff. In a particular place when I use echo command as follows

```
echo Argument 1 - $1 
echo Argument 2 - $2
```

I am getting output as

```
Argument 1 - 2015 0J Oct 
Argument 2 - 8 0 3
```

Basically all fullstops becomes blank space. 
I tried debugging for hours but couldn't find a solution. I believe its something really small.

**EDIT :** I think I found the solution.

Adding

```
IFS=
```

just before echo is solving the issue

Comment: _Inside the script I have lot of complicated stuff_ - please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Do you actually have `echo "Argument 1 - $1"` or are you using `echo Argument 1 - $1` (without the quotes)? If the latter do you also have `IFS=.` somewhere in the script above those lines?

Comment: I don't have IFS=.
Will that solve the problem?

Comment: Main correction, it is echo without quotes.

Comment: IFS=. is not solving the issue
But IFS= is solving the issue

Comment: @etan wasn't suggesting that `IFS=.` is a fix. You have it somewhere in your script and it is causing a problem. At some point, you need to fix that. But the immediate fix is not to change IFS again. Replace `echo $1` with `echo "$1"`. Always quote your expansions.

Comment: Right. My point was that the only way to get your output was to have manually set `IFS` to `.` somewhere in your script and to have those `echo` commands **unquoted**. Both of which are problems you want to fix most likely. As @rici says **always** quote expansions and globally modifying `IFS` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: It works just fine - with or without quotes ( http://i.imgur.com/VuLnxKm.png ). Maybe your script has some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your script, above those `echo` lines you have line like `IFS=.`.

That line is setting the "Internal Field Separator" to `.`. This value is used by the shell to split values into words after expansions are performed.

So with that set (and with the variable unquoted) when the shell expands `$1` to `2015.0J.Oct` it then splits that into `2015`, `0J` and `Oct` and you get the output you see.

The first fix for this is to quote your variable expansions... **Always** quote your variable expansions.

```
echo "Argument 1 - $1"
echo "Argument 2 - $2"
```

The second is to fix whatever in your script requires you to *globally* modify the value of `IFS` to not need you to do that. Changes to `IFS` should, generally, be scoped to as small a bit of code as possible (even just to single commands as is often done with `read`).